# Return to page after save

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to return to the same page in the page list after save. But now after save it will return to page 1 and not return to page 2, or 3..etc - where the  item is that I selected.

I try it like this:

```
if (SaveDbChanges())
{
    // Record an audit trail event for an updated product.
    {
        ATEvent atEvent = AuditTrailHelper.NewEvent(ATEventType.ProductUpdated, HttpContext, db.Schema, entry.Product);
        atEvent.StringArg = entry.Product.Name;
        ATEventLogger.Current.LogEvent(atEvent);
    }
    AddDelayedNotification(Resources.Entity.Environment.ItemSavedMessage, Notification.NotificationType.Success);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = entry.Product.Id });

}
```

So it has to go back to the Index view but then page number 2 in this case. But it goes back to Index view but then on page 1.

Thank you

I try it like this:

Index view:

```
 <a href="@Resources.Action.Navigation.JSVoid,  new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage }" class="sfs-actionbutton btn btn-primary disabled"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.Edit </a>
```

and index method(post):

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditProductModel entry, int page)
        {
            entry.Product.ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(entry.Product).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.Entry(entry.Product).Property(model => model.Guid).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(entry.Product).Property(model => model.CreationDate).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(entry.Product).Property(model => model.IsProduction).IsModified = false;

                entry.Product.IsProduction = StateHelper.IsTestMode() ? false : true;

                HandleProductSelections(entry.Product);
                SerializeAuthenticationSettings(entry);
                SerializePaymentSettings(entry);
                SerializeConnectors(entry);
                SerializePrefillMappings(entry);

                if (SaveDbChanges()) {
                    // Record an audit trail event for an updated product.
                    {
                        ATEvent atEvent = AuditTrailHelper.NewEvent(ATEventType.ProductUpdated, HttpContext, db.Schema, entry.Product);
                        atEvent.StringArg = entry.Product.Name;
                        ATEventLogger.Current.LogEvent(atEvent);
                    }
                    AddDelayedNotification(Resources.Entity.Environment.ItemSavedMessage, Notification.NotificationType.Success);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = entry.Product.Id });
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
                    //return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
                   //return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = page });
                }
            }
            AddDelayedNotification(Resources.Entity.Environment.ItemNotSavedError, Notification.NotificationType.Error);
            return Edit(entry.Product.Id,2,2);
        }
```

and get:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id, int ID, int page)
        {


            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException((int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound, null);
            }

            SetCreateEditProductLists(product, customerSchema);

            EditProductModel editModel = new EditProductModel();
            editModel.Product = product;
            editModel.Db = db;
            //editModel.AuthenticationProviders = AuthenticationProviders.GetProviders(customerSchema);
            //editModel.PaymentProviders = PaymentProviders.GetProviders(customerSchema);
            //editModel.ConnectorProviders = ConnectorProviders.GetProviders(customerSchema);

            DeserializeAuthenticationSettings(editModel);
            DeserializePaymentSettings(editModel);
            DeserializeConnectors(editModel);
            DeserializePrefillMappings(editModel);

            ViewBag.Model = editModel;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;

            return View(editModel);
        }
```

But if I do this:

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage }) " class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i> @Resources.Entity.Product.EditProduct</a>
```

I get this message:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Int32, Int32)' in ''. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

My edit looks now like this:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id, int page)
        {


            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException((int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound, null);
            }

            SetCreateEditProductLists(product, customerSchema);

            EditProductModel editModel = new EditProductModel();
            editModel.Product = product;
            editModel.Db = db;
            //editModel.AuthenticationProviders = AuthenticationProviders.GetProviders(customerSchema);
            //editModel.PaymentProviders = PaymentProviders.GetProviders(customerSchema);
            //editModel.ConnectorProviders = ConnectorProviders.GetProviders(customerSchema);

            DeserializeAuthenticationSettings(editModel);
            DeserializePaymentSettings(editModel);
            DeserializeConnectors(editModel);
            DeserializePrefillMappings(editModel);

            ViewBag.Model = editModel;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;

            return View(editModel);
        }
```

and my post like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditProductModel entry, int page)
        {
            entry.Product.ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(entry.Product).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.Entry(entry.Product).Property(model => model.Guid).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(entry.Product).Property(model => model.CreationDate).IsModified = false;
                db.Entry(entry.Product).Property(model => model.IsProduction).IsModified = false;

                entry.Product.IsProduction = StateHelper.IsTestMode() ? false : true;

                HandleProductSelections(entry.Product);
                SerializeAuthenticationSettings(entry);
                SerializePaymentSettings(entry);
                SerializeConnectors(entry);
                SerializePrefillMappings(entry);

                if (SaveDbChanges()) {
                    // Record an audit trail event for an updated product.
                    {
                        ATEvent atEvent = AuditTrailHelper.NewEvent(ATEventType.ProductUpdated, HttpContext, db.Schema, entry.Product);
                        atEvent.StringArg = entry.Product.Name;
                        ATEventLogger.Current.LogEvent(atEvent);
                    }
                    AddDelayedNotification(Resources.Entity.Environment.ItemSavedMessage, Notification.NotificationType.Success);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = page });
                }
            }
            AddDelayedNotification(Resources.Entity.Environment.ItemNotSavedError, Notification.NotificationType.Error);
            return Edit(entry.Product.Id,92);
        }
```

and my Edit view like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Oke, I solved, like this:

public ActionResult Edit(int? id, int? page)

both in get and post method. but page is always null

The problem is if I do this:

```
[HttpGet]        
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = 2;
```

it will always return to the second page

Why it works if I do it hardcode, like this:  `ViewBag.CurrentPage = 2;`

but if I do this: `ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;` then every time page is null

Thank you

Comment: can you post the code for the "Index" action method please?

Comment: You haven't given all the related code. Need to see the entire edit action and the entire index action, at least.

Comment: Can you post the change to the server with an AJAX call and leave the user in-place on the current view / action?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't send an AJAX request to something like mypage/edit/1/2/3? And there by by passing the need to redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved like this:

in the Index I added:

```
   var id = Session["id"];
   Session["id"] = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way of getting back to page 2 (or 3,4,5) would be to add a hidden variable to your edit page with the page number in it. You will have to keep passing the page number to every page after the index page and use it when you need it.

Another thing that you could do, which will put a lot of strain on your database would be to retrieve a list of all the items, then count where your productID is in the list and then calculate which page it should be on, then go to that page:

```
    var ProductIds = db.Products.Select(x=>x.ProductId).ToArray();
    int MyProductIndex = ProductIds.IndexOf(id);
    int itemsperpage = 30;//or whatever the number of items per page
    var pagenum = Math.Ceiling(myproductIndex/itemsperpage);
```

Comment: But now it is page 2 but I mean in general. So the item can be on page 3 or 4 or 5..etc. But now after save the index view will always show page 1

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me try.